# Object returned from onCreateLoader must not be a non-static inner member class: DumbLoader

Tags: android, android-asynctask, loader

I am trying to implement the `Cursor Loader` and `Custom Cursor Adapter` with the database(Sqlite local database) in 
my android project. I actually want to feed my listview asynchronously with data from my local database with the help of the Cursor Loader and Adapter`. Below is are my class,subclass and methods

```
        // Home Activity class
        public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
                DotCursorAdapter mAdapter;
                private ListView lv;
                private  final int LOADER_ID = 1932;

         DatabaseHandler dbHelper = new DatabaseHandler(this);

         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);
             lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lists);


             mAdapter = new DotCursorAdapter(this, null,0);
             lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);

             getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);   
        }





         @Override
         public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
             return new DumbLoader(this);
         }
         @Override
         public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
             mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
         }
         @Override
         public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
             mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
         }



        /**
         * DumbLoader sub class 
         */ 
         public class DumbLoader extends CursorLoader {
             private static final String TAG = "DumbLoader";
             public DumbLoader(Context context) {
                 super(context);
             }
             @Override
             public Cursor loadInBackground() {
                 Cursor c = dbHelper.fetchAllCountries();

                 return c;

             }
        }






        /**
         * DotCursor Adapter sub class
         */
        public final class DotCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

             public DotCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
                  super(context, cursor, 0);
              }



             @Override
             public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

                  // Find fields to populate in inflated template
                  TextView tvBody = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.header_text);

                  String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("fname"));
                  // Populate fields with extracted properties
                  tvBody.setText(body);


             }
             @Override
              public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                  return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_cardview_activity, parent, false);
              }
            }
    }
```

Below also is my database handler method which fetches the data from the database.

```
public  Cursor fetchAllCountries() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

      Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_LOGIN, new String[] {KEY_ID,KEY_FIRSTNAME},
        null, null, null, null, null);

      if (mCursor != null) {
       mCursor.moveToFirst();
      }
      return mCursor;
     }
```

**The Problem**
On executing this codes above it gives a message error from the log cat and craches the app.

the main error

> Object returned from onCreateLoader must not be a non-static inner
>   member class

Below also is my log cat details

> 09-21 16:13:25.563: D/AbsListView(26541): Get MotionRecognitionManager
>   09-21 16:13:25.568: D/AndroidRuntime(26541): Shutting down VM 09-21
>   16:13:25.573: W/dalvikvm(26541): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x411372a0) 09-21 16:13:25.573:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26541): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 09-21 16:13:25.573:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26541): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.alliswell.alliswell/com.alliswell.alliswell.HomeActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object returned from
>   onCreateLoader must not be a non-static inner member class:
>   DumbLoader{418dc668 id=0} 09-21 16:13:25.573: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
>   09-21 16:13:25.573: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
>   09-21 16:13:25.573: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140) 09-21
>   16:13:25.573: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
>   09-21 16:13:25.573: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-21
>   16:13:25.573: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 09-21 16:13:25.573:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26541):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921) 09-21
>   16:13:25.573: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-21
>   16:13:25.573: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 09-21 16:13:25.573:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26541):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
>   09-21 16:13:25.573: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 09-21
>   16:13:25.573: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-21 16:13:25.573:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26541): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object returned from
>   onCreateLoader must not be a non-static inner member class:
>   DumbLoader{418dc668 id=0} 09-21 16:13:25.573: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.start(LoaderManager.java:257)
>   09-21 16:13:25.573: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.doStart(LoaderManager.java:714)
>   09-21 16:13:25.573: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:556)
>   09-21 16:13:25.573: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1178)
>   09-21 16:13:25.573: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5198) 09-21
>   16:13:25.573: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2083)
>   09-21 16:13:25.573: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):  ... 11 more

I think I am doing something wrong within my codes, I would be grateful if someone could help me solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: The error is pretty clear: move the DumbLoader class outside of the HomeActivity class or make it static.

Comment: public *static* class DumbLoader extends CursorLoader {...}

Answer (score 7):

You have 2 ways to fix this:

1.- Create DumbLoader.java file and set it like this:

```
public class DumbLoader extends CursorLoader {

     private DatabaseHandler mDBHelper;

     public DumbLoader(Context context, DatabaseHandler dbHelper) {
         super(context);
         mDBHelper = dbHelper;
     }

     @Override
     public Cursor loadInBackground() {
         return mDBHelper.fetchAllCountries();
     }
}
```

2.- Use `static` modifier for your Activity's DumbLoader nested class so it gets as following:

```
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    //onCreate(), etc...

    //Make DumbLoader nested class STATIC
    public static class DumbLoader extends CursorLoader {

        private DatabaseHandler mDBHelper;

        public DumbLoader(Context context, DatabaseHandler dbHelper) {
            super(context);
            mDBHelper = dbHelper;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            return mDBHelper.fetchAllCountries();
        }
}
```

Comment: This will not compile, pass dbHelper in constructor -> profit.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Thats true, I will fix it

Answer (score 0):

*LuksProg* and *BamsBamx* suggestions are correct. Just to give more context to it, if you use a *non-static* inner class which extends `AsyncTask` or `AsyncTaskLoader` or if any kind of activity is happening in that class which is not on the main thread then the *Runtime Exception* is thrown. The reason is that if some background task is going on in a non-static inner class and at that time the parent activity is destroyed then there will be a *memory leak* as the inner classes always have a context stored of their parent classes. That's why to prevent the memory leak, any background operations have to be carried out in a static inner class or in a separate individual class. For more insights [see this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309241/warning-this-asynctask-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur)