# onPostExecute() is called on the old Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am developing an app that must be able to rotate during the running of an `AsyncTask`.

I have tried to implement [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) pattern which I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11318942/1770778) post. I also implemented the `onPause()` and `onResume()` and I am able to (re)store my data in the Shared Preferences with json and gson. That part seems to work well.

When my `AsyncTask` calls the `onPostExecute()` without rotating the screen, everything is OK. However, when the screen is rotated **during** the `AsyncTask`, in the `onPostExecute()` my app shows strange behaviour. At a closer look, I noticed while debugging (in Android Studio) my `MainActivity` in `onPostExecute()` has a different ID than the `MainActivity` that is just created with `onCreate()`. So during the `onPostExecute()` the data is processed with the **old** `MainActivity` while another `MainActivity` is already created! And the view is not completely updated until the AsyncTask is finished. This might also be a bad sign...

It is difficult to extract a small project from my code, but as I said, I used the code from [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) blog. The only real difference is, to prevent memory leakage, instead of having an inner `private class DummyTask` I managed to create an (inner) private static class:

```
private static class MoveMrXAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Move> {

    private WeakReference<TaskCallbacks> activityReference;
...
}
```

which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46166223/1770778).

And this is what my onCreate() looks like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
  mTaskFragment = (TaskFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT);

  // If the Fragment is non-null, then it is currently being
  // retained across a configuration change.
  if (mTaskFragment == null) {
    mTaskFragment = new TaskFragment();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(mTaskFragment, TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT).commit();
  }

    viewModel = new MainActivityViewModel(getApplicationContext(), mTaskFragment);
    ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    activityMainBinding.setViewmodel(viewModel);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Have I forgotten something with the `Fragment`? I am using the android.app.Fragment. Is this the correct Fragment-class?

Or might the data binding be the problem? Do I have to unbind all data bindings from the old activity and rebind to the new?

Comment: AFAIK Asyn task as a default strange behaviour while screen config changes try [AsynTaskLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) to overcome the issues. Take a look at this [Link](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts/content/en/Unit%203/71c_asynctask_and_asynctaskloader_md.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It seems that your right and I need a AsynTaskLoader. I will let you know the result.

Comment: welcome glad to help. Happy coding:)

Comment: @Mohamed Mohaideen AH: I have tried to implement an AsyncTaskLoader (from https://medium.com/@sanjeevy133/an-idiots-guide-to-android-asynctaskloader-76f8bfb0a0c0). It is similar to the one in your link. When I run it normally, it works. But when I rotate the screen during the loadInBackground(), it doesn't. Through logging I see that the loadInBackground() is finished, but the onLoadFinished() is never called anymore. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Found it! I didn't realize that I had to trigger the loader again in onResume().