# How to compare the value from handler with the value in activity/fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

There are 3 `handler` in my `fragment` all those contain `AsyncTask`, and the `fragment` contains an `int` value, for example 50. Here what I wanted to do is to compare those 3 `int` value (which I am fetching in those 3 `AsyncTask` in `handler`) with the `int` value defined in `fragment`. For example if `AsyncTask` in `handler-1` gets 80, `AsyncTask` in `handler-2` gets 10, `AsyncTask` in `handler-3` gets 46, then I want to compare these 3 `ints` with that `fragment int`.

I forgot to tell that after comparison, `mFragmentValue` needed to update with new value from `onPostExecute()`.

**My code is big to post here, so here is an example:**

```
class MyFragment{

    int mFragmentValue = 50;;

    void onViewCreated(){
       handler1.post(calling AsyncTask here using runnable); //Here I get 80 in onPostExecute in MyAsyncTask, now I need to compare this 80 with mFragmentValue. These AsyncTasks are sub class of my fragment.
       handler2.post(calling AsyncTask here using runnable); //Here I get 10 in MyAsyncTask, now I need to compare this 10 with mFragmentValue;
       handler3.post(calling AsyncTask here using runnable); //Here I get 46 in MyAsyncTask, now I need to compare this 46 with mFragmentValue;
    }

    static class MyAsyncTask extend AsyncTask{

        void onPostExecute(){
            // getting int here.
            //need to compare fetched int with mFragmentValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can access `mFragmentValue` directly.

Comment: no I can't. `AsyncTask` is static. I just can send the value to `Asynctask` to compare but I need to update `mFragmentValue` from `onPostExecute()`

Comment: `MyAsyncTask` is not static in the code you posted here. Is it in your actual code? If so is there a reason that you cannot make it non-static?

Comment: you can hold the reference to the fragment by using WeakReference. Then get fragment instance, access to mFragmentValue and update it in onPostExecute

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, I am sorry about that but it is static. And because I am getting warning for memory leak, I have to make it static.If I make it non-static I get warning. You can check a question about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309241/warning-this-asynctask-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur

Comment: p.s. I suggest you give a **complete** code example. You should show the code. Words describing what the code does is often helpful. This should always be **in addition** to code, not to replace the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the value of `mFragmentValue` in `MyAsyncTask`, then you can pass it in directly:

class MyFragment{

```
int mFragmentValue = 50;;

    void onViewCreated(){
        AsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask();
        task.execute(mFragmentValue);
    }

    static class MyAsyncTask extend AsyncTask{
        int mTaskValue;

        void doInBackground(Integer...values) {
            mTaskValue = values[0];
        }

        void onPostExecute(){
            // Now use mTaskValue
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there is no need to use a `Handler` nor a `Runnable` with an `AsyncTask`. The purpose of a `Handler` is to facilitate communication between threads, but `AsyncTask` already takes care of this for you. In addition, `doInBackground()` already runs on its own thread and `onPostExecute()` runs on the main thread, so there is no need to create a `Runnable`.

If you need to change the value of `mFragmentValue`, then `MyAsyncTask` **must** have a reference to the `Fragment`. You can do this by making `MyAsyncTask` non-static or add a constructor which accepts a `Fragment` as a parameter (or some interface which your fragment implements). Either way, you must find another way to address the memory leak warning. One solution here to add a method to `MyAsyncTask` that you can call from `onPause()`, `onStop()`, or `onDestroy()`. Calling this method tells the `AsyncTask` that the `Fragment` reference will is no longer valid. Then the `AsyncTask` acts accordingly, probably by aborting its work in `doInBackground()`.