# Is this class leaking a context object?

Tags: java, android

Anyone who has ever worked with Android Studio knows that it has a very helpful code linting capacity that helps programmers avoid common anti-patterns and mistakes.

Such a system is sometimes annoying however, and in this particular case I think it's just being that.

I have a `AsyncTask` like the follwing

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, MyDataType> {
    private Context context;

    MyAsyncTask(Context _context) {
        context = _context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Show a progress dialog or something
        // to indicate that we're doing some work
        // here.
    }

    @Override
    protected MyDataType doInBackground(Void... args) {
        return generateData(); // returns `MyDataType` of course
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(MyDataType data) {
        // Deliver the data and then
        context = null;
    }            
}
```

And of course, Android Studio is kindly telling me that the `context` field leaks a `Context` object.

My questions is,

- is this really leaking the `Context` object? or,
- is `context = null;` guaranteed to run and thus there is no leak?

This is different than [Warning: This AsyncTask class should be static or leaks might occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309241/warning-this-asynctask-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur) because this is NOT A *non-static inner class* of a `Context` like in that case.

**note**: I am not a Java programmer, and I don't understand garbage collection very well. I have mostly worked with c and there I know how memory is managed. Garbage collected languages make me uncomfortable because I don't know how this "*garbage collection*" occurs.

Comment: *is this really leaking the Context object?* yes, it is .... *is context = null; guaranteed to run and thus there is no leak?* no, because nothing guarantee time of that call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: This AsyncTask class should be static or leaks might occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309241/warning-this-asynctask-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur)

Comment: @Justcurious I really don't think this is a duplicate. THIS IS NOT A *non-static inner class*. So it's clearly a different question. In this case I am passing a `Context` object. In that case there is no solution like the one suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48265208/1983495), for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is leaking of `Context`, because your `Context` object can't be garbage collected before your `AsyncTask` wasn't terminated.
`doInBackground()` method can proceed some large operation and before terminating your `Context` will be still alive.
Good practice to wrap your `Context` object into `WeakReference` so if this object can be accessed only by `WeakReference's` it will be collected.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi [This](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/enicholas/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references) is a very good read for `WeakReference`

Comment: @Pulak, the link does not exist