# Static Inner Class in Kotlin

Tags: java, class, static, kotlin

What alternative to an `Inner static Class` can I use in Kotlin Language, if it exists? If not, how can I solve this problem when I need to use a `static class` in Kotlin? See code example below:

```
 inner class GeoTask : AsyncTask<Util, Util, Unit>() {

    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Util?) {

        LocationUtil(this@DisplayMembers).startLocationUpdates()
    }
}
```

I've searched a lot, haven't found anything,  Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What do you need an alternative _for_? What doesn't work?

Comment: in this code in my question, problem(memory Leak) occur because i using asynTask contain (context) of activity, android studio advice me to use (Inner Static class)

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Just omit the `inner` in Kotlin.

**Inner class (holding reference to outer object)**

Java:

```
class A {
    class B {
    ...
    }
}
```

Kotlin:

```
class A {
    inner class B {
    ...
    }
}
```

**Static inner class aka nested class (no reference to outer object)**

Java:

```
class A {
    static class B {
    ...
    }
}
```

Kotlin:

```
class A {
    class B {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also change the "class" to "object"

```
class OuterA {
  object InnerB {
  ... }
}
```

OR

```
object OuterA {
  object InnerB {
  ... }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference in this case?

Comment: It might help:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#object-declarations-overview

Answer (score 0):

In Android world, good practices are:

-Avoid non-static inner classes in activities;

-Use static inner classes with WeakReference so they can be GC-ed (Garbage Collected) when they are not used, as bellow example:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        MySingleton.init(this)
    }
}

object MySingleton {

    var weakContext: WeakReference<Context>? = null

    fun init(ctx: Context) {
        this.weakContext = WeakReference(ctx)
    }
}
```

When the MainActivity instance gets destroyed (onDestroy gets called), this weak reference to its context will get destroyed too; so no memory leaks occur.
:]