# What is the equivalent of Java static class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

There is no `static keyword` in kotlin.

what is the equivalent of `java static class` in kotlin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Static Inner Class in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363450/static-inner-class-in-kotlin)

Comment: There are _several_ past questions which seem to cover this, e.g. [here](/questions/44676853/how-to-create-a-static-class-in-kotlin), [here](/questions/69337288/what-is-the-equivalent-of-java-static-class-in-kotlin), [here](/questions/66969198/how-to-create-truly-static-class-in-kotlin)…

Comment: @gidds, looks like they were asking about the literal `static class`, which is covered by other questions than the ones you linked.

Answer (score 7):

If you just declare a class inside another class, the inner class can be instantiated without an instance of the outer class, similar to Java static classes:

```
class Outer {
    class Inner
}

// can do "Outer.Inner()" directly without an instance of Outer
```

You don't need any modifiers.

If you want something similar to Java's non-static classes, you would need to add the word `inner`:

```
class Outer {
    inner class Inner
}

// need an instance of Outer to create an instance of Outer.Inner
```

To summarise:

|  | needs an outer instance | does not need an outer instance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Java | no modifier | `static` |
| Kotlin | `inner` | no modifier |