# How to replace bean for particular test in SpringBootTest?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I want to avoid connection to Ldap in my integration test so I've added mock of `LDAPConnectionPool` so I have a test class like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
internal class MyControllerTest{

   ...

    @TestConfiguration
    internal class LdapConnectionPoolConfig {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        fun ldapConnectionPool(): LDAPConnectionPool {
            return mockk()
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun foo() {...}
```

When I start test in debug I see that method of inner class is called but production configuration is also called so get an error:

```
The bean 'ldapConnectionPool', defined in ****.MyControllerTest$LdapConnectionPoolConfig, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [****/LdapConnectionPoolConfig.class] and overriding is disabled.
```

I tried to enable overriding by:

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

But at this case I see another error(production config could not be loaded although I expect that it won't be loaded at all):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapConnectionPoolConfig' defined in file [****\LdapConnectionPoolConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name '****.LdapConnectionProperties': Could not bind properties to 'LdapConnectionProperties' : prefix=ldap.connection, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true
```

**P.S.**

If I use top level class for configuration with the same package and name - everything works properly:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Import(LdapConnectionPoolConfig::class)
class MyControllerTest {
```

and

```
@TestConfiguration
class LdapConnectionPoolConfig {
    @Bean
    fun ldapConnectionPool(): LDAPConnectionPool = mockk()
```

If I change config name to `LdapConnectionPoolConfigAnotherName` everything stop working and I see the same error mentioned earlier

But I prefer approach woth inner class

---

### UPDATE

I've prepared Mininal Reproducable Example https://github.com/gredwhite/springboottestconfigissue_demo

And was able to make the code partially working.

In my case I can successfully run the test only in case if class marked with @TestConfiguration has the same name and resides in the same packlge as production configuration class and bean name is the same. Otherwise test tried to load production bean.

**Branch with buggy behaviour  MRE is [here](https://github.com/gredwhite/springboottestconfigissue_demo/tree/bug/config_issue)**

Comment: I took your codebase. Which class to run? Where is the bug?

Comment: @Anish Please run test fron DemoControllerTest

Comment: It executed with no error :)

Comment: Just guide if I'm running it in a wrong way. I want to see the error. :)

Comment: @Anish
Please check that you use correct branch
```
https://github.com/gredwhite/springboottestconfigissue_demo/blob/bug/config_issue/src/test/kotlin/com/example/demo/DemoControllerTest.kt
```

I expect that you cloned master branch and ran on that.

Comment: This branch is correct:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpE0h.png

Comment: @Anish please let me know if you got an error

Comment: I took the code from bug/config_issue branch. I executed the DemoControllerTest. Facing this issue: `Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.example.demo.app.MyProperties.<init>, parameter prop1`

Comment: @AnishB.it is expected. I get the same. So you are on a right way.I want to fix it.

Comment: Yes. You are correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255493/discussion-between-anish-b-and-gstackoverflow).

Comment: what is the issue of this question actually ? do you want to use the `@TestConfiguration` class as the inner class of the test or solve the NPE of the mockk? the github issue that you provided does not match with what your describe in this question.... i am confused

Comment: @Ken Chan to keep it simple. I have bean A in production context. This beans depends on some external resourse like database. I want to replace it with mock bean in tests because I have no database in database (and I don't want to have)

Comment: * in tests environment

Answer (score 0):

In your test class you can declare the field of required type annotated with `@MockBean`:

```kotlin
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
internal class MyControllerTest{
  @MockBean
  private var ldapConnectionPool: LDAPConnectionPool

}
```

Comment: It looks smart but for some reasons it doesn't work and I have no idea why.

Comment: Are you sharing test context across multiple tests?

Comment: How can I check it ?

Comment: If your test class extends another one e.g. `BaseTestClass` having `@SpringBootTest` over it, then the context will be shared across all the inheritors of `BaseTestClass`.

Comment: no - this test is independend at this case.

Comment: Please read topic update - I've added more diagnostic information

Answer (score 0):

For the inner `@TestConfiguration` class to take effect , it must satisfy the following requirements  :

1. static class
2. do not explicitly configure any configuration classes to load the spring context (i.e not specify any `classes` in `@SpringBootTest`/`@ContextConfiguration`). Otherwise , you have to explicitly include it by using `@Import` or  `@SpringBootTest` 's `classes` or `@ContextConfiguration` 's `classes`)

So in any cases , the key requirement is that it must be static. You have already satisfied requirement (2) , so I believe it should solve the issue if you change it to the static inner class which I think in kotlin , it should look something like (reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363450/static-inner-class-in-kotlin)) :

```kotlin
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
internal class MyControllerTest{

    @TestConfiguration
    class LdapConnectionPoolConfig {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        fun ldapConnectionPool(): LDAPConnectionPool {
            return mockk()
        }
    }

}
```