# Why inner AsyncTask needs to be static but Thread doesn't?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In the following example if I declare an `AsyncTask` android studio gives a warning so that I should define it static. According to the [this great explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46166223/764809) we define it as a static class to make it possible for virtual machine to garbage collect the service.

But it appears that thread does not need to be static. Why is that? Is it just android studio that doesn't give a warning or thread behaves in a totally different way?

```
public class MyTrackingService extends Service {

    class TrackingThread extends Thread {
        private final Context cotext;

        TrackingThread(Context context){
            this.cotext = context;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
        }
    }

    class TrackingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private final Context context;

        TrackingTask(Context context){
            this.context = context;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly the same reasoning applies to `Thread` as well. AS just doesn't spit out a warning.

Comment: @Henry Don't you think that it is because thread is for long running operations and therefor when we have a thread inside a service it means that the container service should not be killed and collected at all?

Comment: Frankly no. I think you are interpreting more into it as there actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the following example if I declare an AsyncTask android studio gives a warning so that I should define it static

The Lint warning is over-aggressive. The need for it to be `static` mostly comes with activities and fragments.

Of course, having an `AsyncTask` in a `Service`, as you do here, is pointless. You almost never want to do anything on the main application thread in a `Service`, and the point of `AsyncTask` is to do something on the main application thread when the task completes. Having an `AsyncTask` without `onPostUpdate()` is a code smell and indicates that you should be using something else, such as a regular thread.

Also note that while `AsyncTask` is not officially deprecated, its use is has been frowned upon for the past few years.

> But it appears that thread does not need to be static

It suffers from the same problems that `AsyncTask` does. There just isn't a Lint warning for it.

> Is it just android studio that doesn't give a warning

Correct.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But you mentioned that `AsyncTask` is disapproved by the community. what do they suggest? I myself tend to use Thread and Handlers.

Comment: @a.toraby: For UI-based asynchronous work, `LiveData` backed by RxJava or plain threads seems to be the current recommendation, but keep an eye out for Kotlin coroutines. For a foreground service, usually some sort of `ExecutorService` is appropriate (e.g., `ThreadPoolExecutor`), or possibly RxJava.