# Async should be static error, Kotlin, Android

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin

I am getting this error on this function, I am new to Kotlin programming and not sure how I would fix this. the only answewrs I can find on this are for Java and im not sure how i can convert them

I dont know how to make this static or try and take it out of a nested class any help would be appretiated

> This AsyncTask class should be static or leaks might occur (anonymous
>   android.os.AsyncTask)
>   less... (⌘F1)  A static field will leak contexts.

```
private fun detectAndFrame(imageBitmap: Bitmap) {
        val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream)
        val inputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray())

        val detectTask = object : AsyncTask<InputStream, String, Array<Face>>() {

            var exceptionMessage = ""


            override fun doInBackground(vararg params: InputStream): Array<Face>? {
                try {
                    publishProgress("Detecting...")
                    val result = faceServiceClient.detect(
                        params[0],
                        true, // returnFaceId
                        false, null// returnFaceAttributes:
                        /* new FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType[] {
           FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType.Age,
           FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType.Gender }
           */
                    )// returnFaceLandmarks
                    if (result == null) {
                        publishProgress(
                            "Detection Finished. Nothing detected"
                        )
                        return null
                    }
                    publishProgress(
                        String.format(
                            "Detection Finished. %d face(s) detected",
                            result.size
                        )
                    )
                    return result
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    exceptionMessage = String.format(
                        "Detection failed: %s", e.message
                    )
                    return null
                }
            }

            override fun onPreExecute() {
                //TODO: show progress dialog
                detectionProgressDialog.show()
            }

            override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg progress: String) {
                //TODO: update progress
                detectionProgressDialog.setMessage(progress[0])
            }

            override fun onPostExecute(result: Array<Face>) {
                //TODO: update face frames
                detectionProgressDialog.dismiss()
                if (exceptionMessage != "") {
                    showError(exceptionMessage)
                }
                if (result == null) return
                imageTook.setImageBitmap(
                    drawFaceRectanglesOnBitmap(imageBitmap, result)
                )
                imageBitmap.recycle()
            }
        }

        detectTask.execute(inputStream)
    }


    private fun drawFaceRectanglesOnBitmap(
        originalBitmap: Bitmap, faces: Array<Face>?
    ): Bitmap {
        val bitmap = originalBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        val paint = Paint()
        paint.isAntiAlias = true
        paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        paint.color = Color.RED
        paint.strokeWidth = 10f
        if (faces != null) {
            for (face in faces) {
                val faceRectangle = face.faceRectangle
                canvas.drawRect(
                    faceRectangle.left.toFloat(),
                    faceRectangle.top.toFloat(),
                    (faceRectangle.left + faceRectangle.width).toFloat(),
                    faceRectangle.top + faceRectangle.height.toFloat(),
                    paint
                )
            }
        }
        return bitmap
    }


    private fun showError(message: String) {
        AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Error")
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, id -> }
            .create().show()
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning-this-asynctask-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309241/warning-this-asynctask-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: This AsyncTask class should be static or leaks might occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309241/warning-this-asynctask-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur)

Comment: Hello yhank you for the comments of Duplicate, The duplicate is written for Java. Im not sure how to convert that to Kotlin

Comment: It should be pretty easy to convert Java to Kotlin, even Android Studio does that automatically for you, so that is not an excuse, this post is still a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

try doing:

```
class A {
companion object {
    class MyAsyncTask: AsyncTask <String?, Void,Intent>(){
        protected fun doInBackground(vararg params: String): Intent {
            // do stuff
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(intent: Intent) {
           //do stuff
        }

    }.execute()
}
fun doStuff() {
   MyAsyncTask.execute()
}
}
```