# Class in class inheritance

Tags: android, class, object, inheritance, kotlin

I try to do [this](https://github.com/gifffert/ParseSiteData/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/embersoft/parsesitedata/MainActivity.java), but in Kotlin. I have done that:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var adapter: NewsRecViewAdapter
    var newsItems: ArrayList<NewsItem> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        adapter = NewsRecViewAdapter(newsItems)
        DownloadNews().execute()
    }

    class DownloadNews: AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
            adapter
            super.onPostExecute(result)
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Void {}
    }
}
```

DownloadNews class can't inheritance adapter from MainActivity class. I'd rather not use inner. How can I fix it?

Comment: Don't use AsyncTask. Try Kotlin Coroutines or RxJava, RxKotlin for background tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the class as `inner`

```
inner class DownloadNews: AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
        adapter
        super.onPostExecute(result)
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Void {}
}
```

According [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html#anonymous-inner-classes)

> A nested class marked as inner can access the members of its outer
>   class. Inner classes carry a reference to an object of an outer class

Comment: Yeah, but then Android Studio says `This AsyncTask class should be static or leaks might occur`

Comment: Why not you use separate class for `AsyncTask` or you have to keep it static. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44309450/2637449