# How to decide what should be static in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, static

So, I've got a couple of warnings:
1. Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak
2. This 'AsyncTask' class should be static or leaks might occur.

If I remove static from the field, then my static function, itself called from a statically declared AsyncTask gives a failure.
If I make the other AsyncTask static then I go chasing my tail making other functions and fields static (or at least I initially started to before reverting).

I did see in another answer ([Warning: This AsyncTask class should be static or leaks might occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309241/warning-this-asynctask-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur/46166223#46166223)) for consideration that since the AsyncTask should be short-lived, not to worry about making them static.

I think I understand the difference between static and not, but how should I make the decision for what should/should not be? Have I missed something fundamental about how to interact with the AsyncTaks and using variables?

Comment: Note that `AsyncTask` is deprecated. In general, the only non-constant objects that should be `static` are objects that, by design, need to live for the lifetime of the process. So, for example, a memory cache of data that you load from disk or the network typically winds up either being `static` or being managed by something that itself is `static`. In modern app development, usually libraries are handling our `static` data for us (e.g., Glide with an image cache, Dagger/Koin for dependency inversion).