# Can adding anonymous runnables in the queue of a Handler thread cause a memory leak?

Tags: android, android-handler, android-memory, android-handlerthread, android-threading

Will this code cause a memory leak if it is present in the **Activity** VS **ViewModel** component?

```
    handlerThread = new HandlerThread("myHandlerThread");
    handlerThread.start();
    Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Do work
        }
    }, 1000);

    @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    handlerThread.quit();
}
```

---

Will replacing the anonymous runnable class with a static class that extends Runnable make any difference? This was mentioned @4:13 in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0mkYSjldeA&t=344s) video tutorial!

Why would an anonymous runnable hold reference to an Activity or ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, non-static inner and anonymous classes hold an implicit reference to their outer class. Static inner classes, on the other hand, do not.

Avoid using non-static inner classes in an activity if instances of the inner class could outlive the activity’s lifecycle. Instead, prefer static inner classes and hold a weak reference to the activity inside.

[Source 1](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html)
[Source 2](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/activitys-threads-memory-leaks.html)

As for doing the same in the ViewModel instead of an Activity, if a memory leak occurs it will have a lesser magnitude in case the ViewModel didn't hold a reference to memory-intensive objects that should be garbage collected. But still, a memory leak threat would be still possible.

This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309241/warning-this-asynctask-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur) is also very informative

This [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfQE1ayCzf8&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuD52mtV8NvazNYIyIVPVZRa) contains all about how to properly use Handlers/Threads/HandlerThreads