# Android ProgressBar: visibility not behaving

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I'm having trouble understanding how the visibility of a ProgressBar works. Basically my ProgressBar won't appear or disappear when I need it to.
My code is too big to show all here so I have created a new simple demo project with a button to click:

```
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }
     }
 mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
 mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

I have also tried several versions of the Progressbar; currently it's this:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateTint="#1a09d6"/>
```

So, what happens is that the ProgressBar doesn't turn on and off; it just ends up with whatever is the last state. And the SnackBar doesn't appear either, until after all of the sleeps.
If I could understand how to make this snippet work as I want, then I think would have a solution to the (slightly more complex) situation in my actual code.
I have read other threads and understand that a ProgressBar can't be shown or updated while the main thread is too busy. I have tried, as others have suggested, using

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            })
```

but this makes no difference. I have also tried *View.Invalidate()* between the visibility changes, but to no effect. And I've tried 'INVISIBLE' instead of 'GONE'.
Clearly I'm missing something fundamental about tasks and threading here! Help please.

Comment: You use runOnUiThread wrong... It should be used from other thread..

Comment: Also it obvious why it's not working... You blocked main thread in onClick so no other main thread work is done(fx redrawing - no redraw - no visual changes)

Comment: Ok, you say that I 'blocked the main thread' but this is an out-of-the-box new project created by Android Studio. So your comment is not a lot of help for a newbie! I have now moved the timer code into an async task and the ProgressBar shows up, thanks.But this creates a new problem ('async task should be static') which others seem to disagree about how to deal with: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309241). What a  lot of work just to show a simple progressBar!

Comment: In my 'real' code the intensive work *was* done in async tasks, but I still couldn't get the ProgresBar to show correctly. Now realised that one task was started from 'onActivityResult()' after a file-find intent had been completed. In this case, using the 'runOnUiThread() method has solved it.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation I have found what I was doing incorrectly. Although my code is more complex than this, in effect what I was doing was (in pseudo-code):

```
show progress bar
start task
hide progress bar
```

so it's unsurpising what results, as the bar is hidden as soon as the task starts. So, the progressBar hiding must happen in the task class itself. But then to avoid a problem with potential leaks with a non-static class, an activity 'weak reference' is required:

```
public static class TaskTest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private WeakReference<MainActivity> activityReference;

    TaskTest(MainActivity context) {
        activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        activityReference.get().mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids)
    {
        // do your stuff......shouldn't be more than a few seconds.
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
         }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        activityReference.get().mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

and in the main activity:

```
new TaskTest(MainActivity.this).execute();
```

I'd be glad if someone could confirm that this is the correct approach, or if there is a better way.